# Angular 8 Multi language website for dynamic coontents

Tags: angular, angular-material, localization, internationalization, angular-i18n

I am trying to implement the i18n in my application using json file for language translation. I am able to successfully translate for static text. but i cant able to translate for dynamic text and text that are display in array using *ngFor loops.
Ex:
i am displaying some set of list in dashboard through *ngFor using an array

```
let tempIcons = [{
id: 1,
name: test,
iconName: resultset,
iconDesc: usesd in home page
},
{
id: 2,
name: test12,
iconName: resultset23,
iconDesc: usesd in contact page
},
{
id: 3,
name: test23,
iconName: resultset23,
iconDesc: usesd in about us page
}]
```

Also i want to change language for dynamic text that i am getting from api service from backend. Can anyone give me the example for those scenarios.

I am using Angular 8 with i18n.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use it like:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of tempIcons">
   {{'TRANSLATEPATH.' + item.name.toUpperCase() | translate}} 
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @zach what you mean by 'TRANSLATEPATH'. How I want to declare the json for this array in language json

Comment: Do you use `ngx-translate` with json translate files for each languages or you get the translate from your DB ?

Comment: I am not using ngx-translate I am using angular i18j directly with json translation file